# Nginx How to get the current upstream ip and port

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm using `Nginx-Lua` framework, in log phase, I want to get the current request's upstream ip contains port, In this guide, showed [upstream_addr](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_addr) is something similar, but it species the all upstream servers, not the current one, If I want to get the current one, what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by current one?

Comment: $upstream_addr returns all the upstream addrs, what I want is the request corresponded upstream addr

Comment: It contains multiple addresses only if nginx connected to them (e.g. because first one was down and nginx had to connect to another one). In normal operation there usually only one address. Anyway you could consider last one as 'current'

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks for your reply, what I want is the last one

Comment: You have all power of lua to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$upstream_addr` will return upstream address, which maybe only one or something like this: `192.168.1.1:80, 192.168.1.2:80, unix:/tmp/sock`. You can split the return value by comma:

```
local addrs = _.split(ngx.var.upstream_addr, ',') -- underscore.lua
if #addrs > 0 then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, addrs[#addrs]) -- upstream address you want.
end
```

Comment: Yes `$upstream_addr` will return all the addrs, but what I want is the current one

Comment: The last one always is the current one.